How to decompress a .tar.zst?
currently working on a task where I have to adjust an existing dockerfile to create a new .tar.gz for Python 3.12.2 and frankly, I'm at my wits end.
Here is the script being used:
# The same base image as the jenkins agents
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-bullseye

# install tools we need
WORKDIR /package-install
ADD zstd_*_amd64.deb zstd.deb
RUN dpkg -i zstd.deb

# insert the input packages
WORKDIR /input
ADD cpython-*-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-pgo-*.tar.zst python.tar.zst

# re-compress the tar archive
WORKDIR /build
RUN unzstd /input/python.tar.zst -o ./python.tar
RUN gzip -k ./python.tar

# prepare the output file
RUN cp ./python.tar.gz /python.tar.gz
RUN chmod a=rw /python.tar.gz

# declare the export
VOLUME /export

WORKDIR /

# this will be executed when the container starts
CMD [ "cp", "-va", "/python.tar.gz", "/export/" ]

The Script fails at the unzstd command and tells me that it can't perform the task because allegedly python.tar.zst is a directory.
Nothing I have found so far has helped me solve this issue. If you have any Idea what is causing this issue and how to fix this, I would be glad for your input.
Best Regards
Pascal
Additional Information: cpython-3.12.2+20240224-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-pgo-full.tar.zst is the tar.zst in question.
After I learned this I googled a little and found the possibility of adding -r to the command in order to decompress every file inside the .tar.zst, but this yielded the following error:
The command '/bin/sh -c unzstd -r /input/python.tar.zst/ -o ./python.tar' returned a non-zero code: 1


What happens if you try to treat this file as a directory on your local system. Try to cd cpython-*-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-pgo-*.tar.zst and see what happens. What does it look like when you ls -l cpython-*-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-pgo-*.tar.zst locally?

@JNevill Thank you for your fast response! Your first suggestion yields, that the .tar.zst is not directory. The second one yields: -rwxrwxrwx 1 pmb pmb 49949978 Apr 18 13:19 cpython-3.12.2+20240224-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-pgo-full.tar.zst

Helpful info. Is there more than one file in your local directly that matches those wildcards? I'm wondering too, even if there is only one, because there's wildcards the ADD command may be assuming that more than one file may be piped into the image and so creates python.tar.zst as a directory to catch them. I'd put my money on that if I were a gambler.

Documentation is supporting my assumption: "If multiple  resources are specified, either directly or due to the use of a wildcard, then  must be a directory, and it must end with a slash /." https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#add

It also states this, but I don't think this includes unzstd: "If  is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it's unpacked as a directory. Resources from remote URLs aren't decompressed. "

That's a good thought! I have a shell file that's pulling the tar.zst and a .deb from a remote Nexus Repository, and there were indeed a few remaining from duplicates from my testing. Sadly after deleting them the error persists: zstd: /input/python.tar.zst is a directory -- ignored The command '/bin/sh -c unzstd /input/python.tar.zst -o ./python.tar' returned a non-zero code: 1

I read the same thing regarding the multiple sources, but since there is only ever one tar.zst being pulled, I would habe thought that this does not apply here.

Definitely odd stuff from the documentation. The exclusion of a trailing / would throw an error, according to the documentation (if it were generating a directory), but it's almost definitely creating a directory AND not throwing an error. I'm afraid I lack the expertise on this one. Curious what RUN unzstd /input/python.tar.zst/cpython-3.12.2+20240224-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-pgo-full.tar.zst might do or what that directory would look like if you ended your dockerfile just before the unzstd and shelled into the running container.

I bit the bullet and played w/ docker, was about time, eh?
Anyway: turns out that docker is incredibly stupid in its being smart.  ADD recognises tar files, and generously unpacks them for you; ADD also only accepts directories as the destination. Taking these two things together you actually end up w/ a directory called python.tar.zst under which there's a dir python with your expanded tarball.
Long story short - you can achieve your actual goal this way:
# The same base image as the jenkins agents
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-bullseye

# install tools we need
WORKDIR /package-install
ADD zstd_*_amd64.deb zstd.deb
RUN dpkg -i zstd.deb

# insert the input packages
WORKDIR /input
ADD cpython-*-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-pgo-*.tar.zst /input

# re-compress the tar archive
WORKDIR /build
# prepare the output file
RUN tar cvzf python.tar.gz /input/python
RUN chmod a=rw python.tar.gz

# declare the export
VOLUME /export

WORKDIR /

# this will be executed when the container starts
CMD [ "cp", "-va", "/build/python.tar.gz", "/export/" ]


Thank you for your answer! I'm sorry, but I'm no that skilled in Linux, how would i solve this?

The Answer is correct, I tried performing all steps locally, and they are working fine, they just aren't working in the script.

Sorry, I'm not really any good w/ docker (never used it). What happens when you wrap the RUN unzstd /input/python.tar.zst -o ./python.tar in quotes? RUN "unzstd /input/python.tar.zst -o ./python.tar"? @PascalMichaelBayer

Tried it and it still throws an error: /bin/sh: 1: unzstd /input/python.tar.zst -o ./python.tar: not found The command '/bin/sh -c "unzstd /input/python.tar.zst -o ./python.tar"' returned a non-zero code: 127 @tink

@PascalMichaelBayer as I said, I don't know docker at all. I did some reading of their docu just then, though. Could you try using RUN ["unzstd", "/input/python.tar.zst", "-o", "./python.tar"]?

@PascalMichaelBayer I solved your problem ;D

@PascalMichaelBayer gibts dich noch? :)

Hi, mich gibts noch :D Nutze das WE nur zum Abschalten. So wie es jetzt ist funktioniert es, du bist ein wahrer Lebensretter, :) @tink

@PascalMichaelBayer - fair enough; und freut mich, dir geholfen zu haben. ;)
